# There are some remaning files after performing autoremove

Tags: 14.04

I have installed many programs and noticed that if suppose installation is of 900kb and after removing that installed package it gives 577kb removed where does the 377kb has gone?? if it is in system how to remove the additional data files??

Comment: Could you give an exemple of package with this behaviour ?

Comment: actually all packages are behaving same but for your concern I noticed this when I installed eclipse and removed it by autoremove command..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all the files, even the configuration files, you can use the `purge` option :

```
sudo apt-get purge <package name>
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

But also take into account that when you install *ProgramA* which is dependent of *ProgramB* and *ProgramC*, if you remove *ProgramA* and then run afterward `apt-get autoremove`, it may not remove *ProgramB* and / or *ProgramC*.

I had the case with **eclipse** for which there is a lot of dependent programs to be installed, one of them beeing **ant**. Because on its own **ant** can be used alone, even after `apt-get purge eclipse` and `apt-get --purge autoremove`, **ant** was not removed. I had to remove it manually.

Maybe this is what explain the difference you see in size.

Of cours, it would be better to analyse this with a complete output of your session.

**Remark:**, I've tried with **fslint** as you told in your comment, but the size given in the output of the installation match the one of the remove.

Comment: purge is no help just now I installed fslint package and removed it by purge I still got  308kb of disk space caught by some junk left over by that package... help out